# Select the parts of a line that are within an area in PostGIS

Tags: postgis, sql

In my project I have a road network and many administrative boundaries. My goal is to select the roads that intersect a concrete district but extracting only the parts of the roads that are within that district. I'm quite inexperienced using PostGIS and Spatial SQL and I'm not sure about which function I have to use.

Answer (score 2):

You can make use of [`st_intersection`](https://postgis.net/docs/ST_Intersection.html)  to get the part of the roads that are within your boundary. If a road is fully within, it will be completely returned, else it will be cut and only the intersecting sections will be kept. Beware that one original street segment (with 1 ID) could end up in several segments so you may want to create a new primary key.

You would compute the intersection only on features that do intersect, and restrict to the proper administrative unit(s).

The example from the doc is quite explicit:

```sql
---Clip all lines (trails) by country (here we assume country geom are POLYGON or MULTIPOLYGONS)
-- NOTE: we are only keeping intersections that result in a LINESTRING or MULTILINESTRING because we don't
-- care about trails that just share a point
-- the dump is needed to expand a geometry collection into individual single MULT* parts
-- the below is fairly generic and will work for polys, etc. by just changing the where clause
SELECT clipped.gid, clipped.f_name, clipped_geom
FROM (SELECT trails.gid, trails.f_name, (ST_Dump(ST_Intersection(country.the_geom, trails.the_geom))).geom As clipped_geom
FROM country
    INNER JOIN trails
    ON ST_Intersects(country.the_geom, trails.the_geom))  As clipped
    WHERE ST_Dimension(clipped.clipped_geom) = 1 ;
```